# Flaskr Delete posts(flaskr example)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So I started following the flaskr example and I got everything to run correctly. I started to work on a way to delete posts I added by using the the entry.id method but when I try to delete posts I get a 500 error saying

" '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'db' "

at first I removed the global scope but that resulted in the same error.

this is what my routes looks like.

The '/' route

---

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text, id from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [{"title" : row[0], "text" : row[1], "id" : row[2]} for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

---

Delete Route

---

```
@app.route('/delete/<entry_id>')
def delete_entry(entry_id):
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    g.db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + entry_id)
    g.db.commit()
    flash('Entry was succesfully removed')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

---

Any ideas why I might be getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: `g` is a dictionary-like object. You're trying to do an attribute lookup. You may want to do `g.get("db")` depending how you put the db in there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use db = get_db() and db.execute as same as show_entries